# How to upload video to facebook pages feed with facebook SDK for android version 3.6?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, upload

I am using this graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/ to upload video to pages feed. There said that the video must be encoded as multipart/form-data, How can I get the needed format to put it to Bundle object?
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code, where I try to read file as byteArray but it doesn`t work.
I'm getting the error message: ***"(#352) Sorry, the video file you selected is in a format that we don't support."***

```
private boolean uploadVideo (File video) {
        Session session = mSession;
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
//            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(RecActivity.this, "publish_actions"));

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            byte[] data = null;
            String dataPath = video.toString();
            String dataMsg = "My First Video";
            String dataName ="My First";
            AssetManager am =  getApplicationContext().getAssets();
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
                data = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }


            params.putByteArray("source", data);
            params.putString("message", dataMsg);
            params.putString("filename", dataName);
            /* make the API call */
            new Request(
                    session,
                    "/1442150402671811/videos",
                    params,
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(final Response response) {

                            if (response.getError().getErrorMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        new AlertDialog.Builder(RecActivity.this).setMessage("Uploaded...")
                                                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                                        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                                                    }
                                                }).show();
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println(response.getError().getErrorMessage());
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        new AlertDialog.Builder(RecActivity.this).setMessage(response.getError().getErrorMessage())
                                                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                                        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                                                    }
                                                }).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Try using Request.newUploadVideoRequest rather than constructing your own Request. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/Request/#newUploadVideoRequest

Comment: Request.newUploadVideoRequest uploads the video to user's default album.   But I need to upload it to specified page videos.

Comment: try using newUploadVideoRequest to create the request, and then call setGraphPath on the created request to be your specific path.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to set "graph-video.facebook.com/{page-id}/videos" path. Returns error.
Is there another way to do that?

Comment: When you call setGraphPath, the parameter should be only "{page-id}/videos", not the host.